# jquery selector for td in a table

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

i want to get a event that will fire when i click inside a td of a html table

i had this:

```
 ('td').live('click', function() {
            alert($(this).attr('id'));
        });
```

which works but this fires inside the 'th" cells as well (not sure why).

is there any selector that just fires inside td's and not th's.  I tried this:

```
 ('tbody td').live('click', function() {
            alert($(this).attr('id'));
        });
```

but that didn't seems to stop this firing for the th's.

### EDIT:

I figured out the issue..  the problem is that the whole table was inside another table so even the "th" was actually inside a "td" of a larger table.

The solution was to do this:

```
 $('table.calendar td').live('click', function() {
            alert($(this).attr('id'));
        });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out the issue. The problem is that the whole table was inside another table so even the "**th**" was actually inside a "**td**" of a larger table.

The solution was to do this:

```
 $('table.calendar td').live('click', function() {
            alert($(this).attr('id'));
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

If it's not done already, put your `th` in `thead` and your `td` in `tbody` :

```
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>my</th><th>title</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>my</td><td>content</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Does this help ?

Comment: Why has someone given this a down vote? It seems like a totally reasonable response to me even if it doesn't fix the problem!!!

Comment: @Pierre Henry - problem fixed.  see above

Comment: I just removed down-votes for both the minused answers here. I agree, I don't think it's helpful to downvote, especially without explanation, when the intention of an answer is to aid in tracking down the problem.